# Query RDF file using PHP and SPARQL. Help and suggestions?

Tags: php, rdf, sparql, virtuoso

What is the endpoint for Virtuoso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Virtuoso server the default SPARQL endpoint will be at the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8890/sparql
```

It is likely your code is not working because you are using a non-SPARQL endpoint as the URL

Comment: Thanks. I found that was the problem. Silly of me really.